# PrimeNG and mocking confirmation service

Tags: angular, mocking, primeng

I have a problem trying to mock the PrimeNG confirmation service, so I can test the accept function.
I've got the following method on my component

```
deleteRow(rowData: any): void{

      this.confirmationService.confirm({
        message: 'Are you sure that you want to perform this deletion?',
        accept: (): void => {
          this.messageService.add({
            severity: 'success',
            summary: `Deleted`,
            detail: `Deleted ${rowData.name}`
          });

          const index: number = this.areas.indexOf(rowData);
          this.areas.splice(index, 1);
        }
    });
  }
```

and the following  test

```
    const confirmationService: ConfirmationService = TestBed.get(ConfirmationService);

    const mockConfirm: any = spyOn(confirmationService, 'confirm').and.callFake((c: any) => {
      c.accept();
    });
    component.deleteRow({id: 'aaa'});

    expect(mockConfirm).toHaveBeenCalled();
    
  });
```

and here is my testbed setup

```
  beforeEach(async(() => {
      TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
        declarations: [AreasListComponent],
        imports: [FormsModule,
          ReactiveFormsModule,
          ConfirmDialogModule,
          FieldsetModule,
          TableModule,
          ToastModule,
          DropdownModule,
          NoopAnimationsModule
        ],
        providers: [
          ConfirmationService,
          MessageService
        ]
      })
        .compileComponents();
    })
  );
```

the mockconfirm `toHaveBeenCalled` fails, and when I debug it, doesn't seem to have the mock on the service.

Has anyone got any ideas?

Regards

Comment: could you `console.log` or debug fake callback to see if it is being invoked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like the problem is that `confirm` method is on `ConfirmationService` prototype and not on the object it self. When you are spying on `confirm` method, you are spying on instance specific method and hence its not working.

[image]

Try following code and it should work:

```
const mockConfirm: any = spyOn(ConfirmationService.prototype, 'confirm').and.callFake((c: any) => {
  c.accept();
});
```

Comment: hi, thanks that pointed me in the right direction. I had to use  `const mockConfirm: any = spyOn(confirmationService.__proto__, 'confirm').and.callFake((c: any) => {
            c.accept();
          });`

Comment: but how it is added on prototype ? https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/master/src/app/components/api/confirmationservice.ts#L14

Comment: @pathe.kiran you are looking at typescript file, to understand how `ConfirmationService` is defined, you should look at js files generated after compiling ts files.